# How to combine json code to show comment number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, blogger

Recently I have created a simple code for my blogger or blogspot website to show Author's Data, like author's name with URL, image and their published Posts number.

Then I tried to show the comments number of the Author's. By this url `https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=500&callback=handleJsonpData` we can get a blogger websites all comments. Here we can get All comments with the Name, Comments Messages and many.

So what I tried, to show the number of comments of the Author's alongside their name. I have write this code, but It's not working. There are three author in my blog site, any one of them have some comments in the site.

There are two sectors of my code. I want to make a combination of both code to show comments number of the authors if the authors have any comment.

**This is 1st part to get comments**. Here I manually applied a name and checked if the name have comments, and show the number.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="comment-count"></div>
<div id="iacman-comment-count"></div>

<script>
  function displayCommentCount(data) {
    var totalCommentCount = 0;
    var iacmanCommentCount = 0;
    if ('entry' in data.feed) {
      totalCommentCount = data.feed.entry.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var authorName = data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
        if (authorName === 'Iacman') {
          iacmanCommentCount++;
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('comment-count').innerHTML = '<h2>Total Comments: ' + totalCommentCount + '</h2>';
    document.getElementById('iacman-comment-count').innerHTML = '<h2>Comments by Iacman: ' + iacmanCommentCount + '</h2>';
  }
  function handleJsonpData(data) {
    displayCommentCount(data);
  }
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=500&callback=handleJsonpData';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

**This is the second part to get The Blog Author's Details.**

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dfc182d96.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>.author-image {cursor: pointer;}</style>

<div class="mb-0 mt-12">
  <h4 class="mb-0 text-black dark:text-gray-300"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-vneck-hair"></i> Authors and Writers </h4>
</div>
<div class="tbt_all_authors-list mt-0 mb-16 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5"></div>

<script>
  let feedURL = "https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=500";
  $.getJSON(feedURL, function(data) {
    let authors = [];
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(index, entry) {
      if (entry.author) {
        let authorName = entry.author[0].name.$t;
        let authorImage = entry.author[0].gd$image.src;
        let authorProfileUrl = entry.author[0].uri.$t; // Extract the author profile URL
        let authorExists = false;
        let authorIndex;
        $.each(authors, function(index, author) {
          if (author.name === authorName) {
            authorExists = true;
            authorIndex = index;
          }
        });
        if (authorExists) {
          authors[authorIndex].count++;
        } else {
          authors.push({ name: authorName, image: authorImage, count: 1, profileUrl: authorProfileUrl });
        }
      }
    });
    authors.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.count - a.count;
    });
    $.each(authors, function(index, author) {
      let html = '<div class="flex bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 shadow rounded">' +
        '<a href="' + author.profileUrl + '" target="_blank" class="author-image flex items-start px-3 py-3">' +
        '<div class="w-20 h-20 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow" style="background-image: url(' + author.image + '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>' +
        '<div class="">' +
        '<div class="flex items-center justify-between">' +
        '<div class="text-md font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 mt-3">' + author.name + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Posts: ' + author.count + ' </div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '</div>';
      $('.tbt_all_authors-list').append(html);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to combine both codes to find the comment number of the Author's. If Authors have any comment, it should show the number automatically. I don't know how to combine both codes to show the comments number of author if Authors have any comment. Somebody please help me to find out. I tried in many ways, but not working.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Is there an error in your console? Have you ensured that all functions are indeed executing?

Comment: @mykaf I tried many ways to get the comments number of Authors. But not get. Please help me. I exactly don't know what's the problem.

Comment: We know much less what the problem is because we're not running the code. You need to give us as much information as possible

Comment: You haven't answered some crucial questions, though: What have you done to debug this? Is there an error in your console? Have you ensured that all functions are indeed executing?

Comment: @infinitezero I have updated code and explained everything. Please check this and help me.

Comment: @mykaf please check the new code brother.

Comment: @infinitezero please check the new code brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you're trying to access author.name in the displayCommentCount function, but author is not defined within the scope of that function. author is defined in the $.getJSON callback function and it is not globally accessible.

To fix the issue, you need to update your displayCommentCount function to accept authorName as a parameter, then compare it with each comment author's name.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dfc182d96.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>.author-image {cursor: pointer;}</style>

<div class="mb-0 mt-12">
  <h4 class="mb-0 text-black dark:text-gray-300"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-vneck-hair"></i> Authors and Writers </h4>
</div>
<div class="tbt_all_authors-list mt-0 mb-16 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5"></div>

<script>
  var commentData;

  function getCommentCount(authorName) {
    var sfwCommentCount = 0;
    if ('entry' in commentData.feed) {
      for (var i = 0; i < commentData.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var commentAuthorName = commentData.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
        if (commentAuthorName === authorName) {
          sfwCommentCount++;
        }
      }
    }
    return sfwCommentCount;
  }

  function handleJsonpData(data) {
    commentData = data;
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=500&callback=handleJsonpData';
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  let feedURL = "https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=500";
  $.getJSON(feedURL, function(data) {
    let authors = [];
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(index, entry) {
      if (entry.author) {
        let authorName = entry.author[0].name.$t;
        let authorImage = entry.author[0].gd$image.src;
        let authorAbout = '';
        if (entry.author[0].gd$about) {
          authorAbout = entry.author[0].gd$about.$t;
        }
        let authorProfileUrl = entry.author[0].uri.$t; // Extract the author profile URL
        let authorExists = false;
        let authorIndex;
        $.each(authors, function(index, author) {
          if (author.name === authorName) {
            authorExists = true;
            authorIndex = index;
          }
        });
        if (authorExists) {
          authors[authorIndex].count++;
        } else {
          authors.push({ name: authorName, image: authorImage, count: 1, about: authorAbout, profileUrl: authorProfileUrl });
        }
      }
    });

    authors.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.count - a.count;
    });

    $.each(authors, function(index, author) {
      let authorCommentCount = getCommentCount(author.name);
      let html = '<div class="flex bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 shadow rounded">' +
        '<a href="' + author.profileUrl + '" target="_blank" class="author-image flex items-start px-3 py-3">' +
        '<div class="w-20 h-20 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow" style="background-image: url(' + author.image + '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>' +
        '<div class="">' +
        '<div class="flex items-center justify-between">' +
        '<div class="text-md font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 mt-3">' + author.name + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Posts: ' + author.count + ' </div>' +
        '<div class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Comments: ' + authorCommentCount + ' </div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '</div>';

      $('.tbt_all_authors-list').append(html);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You somehow used `sfwCommentCount` variable in html element that was out of that scope, that's why its not working

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dfc182d96.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .author-image {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<div class="mb-0 mt-12">
    <h4 class="mb-0 text-black dark:text-gray-300"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-vneck-hair"></i> Authors and Writers</h4>
</div>
<div
    class="tbt_all_authors-list mt-0 mb-16 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5"></div>

<script>
    let feedURL = "https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=10";
    let authors = [];
    $.getJSON(feedURL, function (data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (index, entry) {
            if (entry.author) {
                let authorName = entry.author[0].name.$t;
                let authorImage = entry.author[0].gd$image.src;
                let authorAbout = "";
                if (entry.author[0].gd$about) {
                    authorAbout = entry.author[0].gd$about.$t;
                }
                let authorProfileUrl = entry.author[0].uri.$t; // Extract the author profile URL
                let authorExists = false;
                let authorIndex;
                $.each(authors, function (index, author) {
                    if (author.name === authorName) {
                        authorExists = true;
                        authorIndex = index;
                    }
                });
                if (authorExists) {
                    authors[authorIndex].count++;
                } else {
                    authors.push({
                        name: authorName,
                        image: authorImage,
                        count: 1,
                        about: authorAbout,
                        profileUrl: authorProfileUrl,
                        comment: 0,
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        authors.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.count - a.count;
        });

        $.each(authors, function (index, author) {
            let html =
                '<div class="flex bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 shadow rounded">' +
                '<a href="' +
                author.profileUrl +
                '" target="_blank" class="author-image flex items-start px-3 py-3">' +
                '<div class="w-20 h-20 rounded-full object-cover mr-4 shadow" style="background-image: url(' +
                author.image +
                '); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>' +
                '<div class="">' +
                '<div class="flex items-center justify-between">' +
                '<div class="text-md font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 mt-3">' +
                author.name +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                '<div class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Posts: ' +
                author.count +
                " </div>" +
                `<div class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400" id="${author.name}-comment">Comments: ` +
                author.comment +
                " </div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</a>" +
                "</div>";

            $(".tbt_all_authors-list").append(html);
        });
    });

    function displayCommentCount(data) {
        if ("entry" in data.feed) {
            totalCommentCount = data.feed.entry.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                var authorName = data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
                console.log(authors.filter((author) => author.name === authorName).length > 0);

                if (authors.filter((author) => author.name === authorName).length > 0) {
                    authors.forEach((author) => {
                        if (author.name === authorName) author.comment++;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        authors.forEach((author) => {
            // $(`#${author.name}-comment`)[0].innerText =`Comments: ${author.comment}`;
            document.getElementById(`${author.name}-comment`).innerText = `Comments: ${author.comment}`;
        });
    }

    function handleJsonpData(data) {
        displayCommentCount(data);
    }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
        "https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10&callback=handleJsonpData";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: What have you done...? Now It's showing wrong informations.  The "Iacman" author have "87" posts. But now it showing Just "8" posts. Again it not even showing comment numbers too..